# How do I access localStorage on getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I'm building a next js application. I have implemented jwt in it. So whenever the user request the data from the database, a middleware is called, checks if the req.body.token and validates it. if it is, then server responds with the data else redirect the user to login.js and the token from the localstorage is get removed.
So my question is, Is something wrong with this approach? Secondly, if I can't have access to localStorage how do I validate user on each request? I know I can do it by making fetch api call in useEffect from the client side. but I want to render the page on server side. is there something I should know?

Comment: "Secondly, if I can't have access to localStorage how do I validate user on each request?" -  by authenticating their session/auth cookie. Your login process should issue such a cookie which will automatically be included in all requests: normal browser window requests, XHR, and `fetch` (though you need to specify `credentials: 'include'` ofc).

Comment: Accessing `localStorage` inside `getServerSideProps` isn't possible, as that runs on the server-side. I'd recommend updating the title of the question, as what you ultimately want is a way to authenticate users on the server-side (and for that you should use cookies as @Dai mentioned above).

Answer (score 2):

You can't because getServerSideProps always runs on the server and `localStorage` is part of the `window` object which is only available in the browser